# WinForms открыть/скрыть окна

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал библиотеку классов C#, добавил два окна WinForms: `Form1` и `Form2`
Запускается сторонней программой таким образом

```
namespace NewTestLibrary2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static Form1 mainform1;
        static Form2 mainform2;
        static Thread threadmainform;
        public Form2 Form_2;

        [DllExport]
        public static void Init()
        {
            if (mainform1 == null)
            {
                threadmainform = new Thread(NewForm1);
                threadmainform.Start();
            }
            if (mainform2 == null)
            {
                threadmainform = new Thread(NewForm2);
                threadmainform.Start();
            }
        }

        [DllExport]
        public static void DeInit(int reason)
        {
            if (reason == 3 || reason == 5) return;
            if (mainform2 != null) { mainform2.Close(); Thread.Sleep(100); }
            if (mainform1 != null) { mainform1.Close(); Thread.Sleep(1000); }
            if (threadmainform != null) threadmainform.Join();
            mainform1 = null;
            mainform2 = null;
            threadmainform = null;
        }

        private static void NewForm1()
        { mainform1 = new Form1(); mainform1.ShowDialog(); }
        private static void NewForm2()
        { mainform2 = new Form2(); mainform2.ShowDialog(); }
    }
}
```

На окне `Form1` есть кнопка.
Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менять видимость `Form2`?
Нужен конкретный пример. (Я только начал это дело изучать)

код `Form1`

```
namespace NewTestLibrary2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //---
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в колбэке кнопки `Form2.Visible = !Form2.Visible;`

Comment: как из первой формы задать значение для второй. Я новичок и многое не понимаю(

Comment: для начала сохрани в классе первой формы ссылку на вторую. где это можно сделать? - там где ты создаешь обе формы и запускаешь приложение

Comment: Мне бы пример какой нибудь, я ничего не понял. Я создал библиотеку классов C# и добавил в проект два окна WinForms. На первом окне кнопа отобразить или скрыть второе окно. Я только начал это дело изучать)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос так

```
public bool Form2Visible
{
    get => form2.Visible;
    set => form2.Visible = value;
}
private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (form2.Visible == true) { form2.Visible = false; label1.Text = "Show";    }
    else { form2.Visible = true; label1.Text = "Hide"; }
}
```

Comment: `if (form2.Visible == true)` можно написать как `if (form2.Visible)`. И зачем свойство `Form2Visible` если вы его никак не используете?

Comment: Но вообще весь метод можно написать так `{ form2.Visible = !form2.Visible; label1.Text = form2.Visible ? "Hide" : "Show"; }`

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Answer (score 0):

За показ и скрытие формы отвечают методы Show и Hide.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Show();

form1.Hide();
```

Comment: это я уже читал но...мне желательно пример. я сделал так     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(); form2.Show();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(); form2.Visible = false;
        }
но не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста оставяйте более развернутые ответы, чтобы они не вызывали дополнительных вопросов у автора.